# String Encoding Program

Tags: c#, string, encoding

Test Case :

```
banagalore (of type String)
```

Expected Output :

```
{30,20,21,92,20,80,32,31,02}
```

I Have converted them to ASCII using C# , now I'm not able to convert them to that sequence, kindly suggest some ideas .

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter The String ");
            string str = Console.ReadLine();
            byte[] b = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
            foreach (var item in b)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ASCII ?? can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Just Need to Convert the String to that sequence , i have one of the test case as mentioned above . I Think The Logic Must Be to Convert Each Char in String To ASCII Value then Figure out what must be done , I'm Stuck After that

Comment: SO is not really a place to solve puzzles - while finding what operation transforms "banagalore" to `{30,20,21,92,20,80,32,31,02}` may be entertaining but not good fit for SO. (i.e. it clearly not character codes in any encoding I know of)

Comment: What is the logic to `Convert the String to that sequence` ?

Comment: Yea ,I Know We Must but i must figure out the logic for that .

Comment: well, figure out the logic, try to implement in C, then if you get errors, we are here to help. :-)

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh:I Just Thought of Converting it to ASCII and then fogure something out , If u Have any other logic  UR Most Welcome .

Comment: I tried it for more than 3hrs ,tried to think of every logic possible ,im just thoughtless rite now , Just Give Me any Clue r suggestion

Comment: @user3326623 I don't uderstand your expected output. Here your program prints`65 66 67` for an input of `ABC`. And that seems perfectly correct to me. What are you trying to do actually ? What are **you** expecting as output for an input `ABC` ?

Comment: @user3326623 do you have more test cases ?

Comment: No . Just One . all I need the idea to encode bangalore to {30,20,21,92,20,80,32,31,02}

Comment: What's the goal of this ? Is this an assignment ? Seems completely weird to me

Answer (score 0):

A XOR mask would be one option.

```
byte[] input = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("bangalore");
var known_result = new byte[] { 30, 20, 21, 92, 20, 80, 32, 31, 02 };
var computed_mask = new byte[input.Length];

for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    computed_mask[i] = (byte)(known_result[i] ^ input[i]);
}

byte[] test = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("bangalore");
for (var i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
{
    test[i] ^= computed_mask[i];
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", test));
```